# rails 3, paperclip assigns id 0 when uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, formtastic

iam using rails with formtastic for my admin backend. i want to be able to upload an image to my recordset, and i try to use paperclip to to that.

when i edit a recordset, the upload of the image works just fine. when i try to CREATE a NEW recordset, paperclip seems to assign the ID 0 for that image in my upload path!

```
#expected path for new image:
/public/logos/2342/some_image.png


#and thats what i get when i create my new record-set:
/public/logos/0/some_image.png
```

i tried to add attr_accessible to my model

```
attr_accessible :logo_file_name, :logo_content_type, :logo_file_size, :logo_updated_at
```

but that throws me an sql-error

Column 'logo_file_size' cannot be null

EDIT: solved the mysql error when i add attr_accessible. i just allowed the logo_file_size to be null. but the id=0 problem still exists...

my code:

MODEL:

```
has_attached_file :logo, 
              :url => "/:class/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension", 
              :styles => { :original => ["150x150>", :png] }
```

VIEW:

```
<%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :logo, :as => :file %>
    <%= f.input :link, :as => :url %>
    <%= f.input :published, :published => 'Veröffentlicht' %>
<% end %>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def create
  Article.create(params[:article])
end
```

my datebase has these 4 colums in Article-Table:
    logo_file_name
    logo_content_type
    logo_file_size
    logo_updated_at

iam using rails 3.1.1, formtastic 1.2.4, paperclip 2.4.5

thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: it seems that my files get uploaded as PNG as i want it, but in the database-table the original is kept. thats the problem for new and existing records. for me it seems that iam missing something that tells the logo to which record it is associated...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i know its a bit late, but i found the problem and will share the answer for everyone with the same problem.

problem was mysql, upgraded to mysql2 gem, and everything worked as expected